# Modular invariants of special linear groups acting on exterior powers

Tags: invariant-theory, modular-representation-theory

In general it can be very difficult to compute the invariants of a group acting on a module which is not a vector space over an infinite field. I am interested in the following example, motivated by computations in algebraic topology.

Let $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ be group of invertible $(n \times n)$-matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ and determinant 1. This acts on $\mathbb{Z}^n$, hence on the exterior power $\Lambda^i \mathbb{Z}^n$, and thus on the tensor product $\Lambda^i \mathbb{Z}^n \otimes \mathbb{Z}/m$.

> Are there any triples of integers $n \geq 2$, $0<i<n$, and $m \geq 2$, so that $\Lambda^i \mathbb{Z}^n \otimes \mathbb{Z}/m$ contains non-zero $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$-invariants?

Comment: One may assume $m$ is prime. Then we are dealing with minuscule representations and the answer is NO.

Comment: One notes that the invariant is killed by matrices with one nonzero entry, off the diagonal. Now just compute explicitly with respect to the standard bases.

Comment: One may also use  that $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ contains representatives of its Weyl group and that an invariant has to be fixed  by them. But the Weyl group acts transitively on the standard basis of $\Lambda^i(\mathbb{Z}^n)$, so this means an invariant would be a scalar multiple of the sum of the basis.

Comment: Up to signs, that is. Also use diagonal matrices.

Comment: Yes, I think this works. Thanks!